# Abbrevations are not coming in google speech api

Tags: google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am using google speech API my target audience are having British accent but i am getting good results when i am using **en-US** language code. The team for which we are building speech to text uses a lot of abbreviations which are not coming in the response. I tried providing the abbreviations in **speech_context** but still no luck. Can anyone help me with custom words/abbreviations. I have also tried passing phrase instead of the abbreviation in **speech_context** but nothing seems to be working. I am using enhanced video model. I have even used **$OOV_CLASS_ALPHANUMERIC_SEQUENCE** in speech_context but the result gets worse.

Below is my configuration

```
config = {
    "language_code": "en-US",
    "sample_rate_hertz": 48000,
    "encoding": enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
    "model":"video",
    "use_enhanced":True,
    "enable_automatic_punctuation":True,
    "profanity_filter": True,
    "max_alternatives":2,
    "speech_contexts":[{"phrases":["MTU"]}]
    
}
```

> Transcript: TSU has tripped on TSU for reset. Okay, empty you 10 - 2 T
> XC y - 0 return the surface
>
> Expected Transcript: TSU has tripped on TSU4 reset ok MTU 10-2 and TNC
> 118-0 returned to service